# List index out of range when appending text from files

Tags: python, python-3.x, index-error

The code below throws an `IndexError` saying `list index out of range` but when I print the item on that index, it shows that there is text there.

So why am I getting an index error?

code:

```
paths = []
formats = []

with open("config.cf","r") as config_file:

    global sort_mode
    sort_mode = config_file.readline().replace("\n","").split(":")

    if sort_mode[1] == "custom":

        for line in config_file:

            temp = str(line).replace("\n","").split("/")

            if temp[0] == "mode:":
                continue

            format_list = str(temp[0]).split(",")

            paths.append(temp[1]) # <---- Error
            formats.append(format_list)
```

the first line of the "Config file" is `mode:custom` and the second is `.txt/text`

When i do  `print(temp[1])` i get "text" and the "index error" at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You file contains a `\n` at the end of it - the line after is "empty".

This `temp = str(line).replace("\n","").split("/")` returns a list with 1 element.

Afterwards you access this list with `temp[1]` - this causes the indexing error.

Next time you get such an error, replace the access-line with a print of the list, this gives you a good idea whats wrong.

Use

```
if len(temp) < 2 or temp[0] == "mode:":
    continue
```

Empty lists are falsy and it would continue afterwards.

The other thing you can always do if you encounter exceptions: catch them.

```
try:

    print( [][20])
except IndexError as e:
    print(e)
```

---

Code to test it (use first the one then the other create-code for config.cf):

```
# works
with open("config.cf","w") as f:
    f.write("""mode:custom
.txt/text""")

# fails
with open("config.cf","w") as f:
    f.write("""mode:custom
.txt/text
 """)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I edited my "Config.cf" file with notepad++ and left some empty lines at the end of the file, so I deleted them and it works now.